# Fails to display mp3 files in TreeView in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qfilesystemmodel

Alright I seem to have come across a situation where I need to traverse my directories and search for only .mp3 and .mpeg files. Once searched, I want to display them in my tree view.

Basically I have 2 tree views in my app, one displays the system directories and other should display only .mp3 and .mpeg files.

Here is the code

```
// Gets called when application starts
void DetailView::onCamStartup()
{
m_SystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
m_SystemListViewModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
m_SystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
ui->DriveView->setModel(m_SystemModel);
ui->DriveListView->setModel(m_SystemListViewModel);

// regard less how many columns you can do this using for:
for(int nCount = 1; nCount < m_SystemModel->columnCount(); nCount++)
   ui->DriveView->hideColumn(nCount);
}

// Displays Files in Detail View on Clicking Drive
void DetailView::on_DriveView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
QString sPath = m_SystemModel->fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath();
ui->DriveListView->setRootIndex(m_SystemListViewModel->setRootPath(sPath));

m_SystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
m_SystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs );
m_SystemListViewModel->setFilter( QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );

QStringList m_list;
QDirIterator dirIt(sPath,QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

while (dirIt.hasNext())
{
    dirIt.next();
    if (QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).isFile())
    {
        if (QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).suffix() == "mp3" || QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).suffix() == "mpeg")
        {
            qDebug()<<dirIt.filePath();
            m_list<<dirIt.filePath();
            m_list.append(dirIt.filePath());
        }
    }

    m_SystemListViewModel->setNameFilters(m_list);
    m_SystemListViewModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);
}
}
```

where `DriveView` is the treeview which displays drives and `DriveListView` is the treeview which should display only mp3 and mpeg files. When I debug the code, `qDebug()<<dirIt.filePath();` gives me the path of all .mp3 and .mpeg files in `Application Output` tab but doesnt display them inside the DriveListView(treeview). As of now it displays only the files in the drive but the subfolders inside the drive also have mp3 files which are not displayed.

Here is the pic for reference:
[image]

Notice there are many folders inside SONGS where mp3 files are present but it doesnt display.

Where am i making mistake???

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the call to
`m_SystemListViewModel->setFilter( QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );` will explicitly tell Qt to only shows files.

[According to the documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdir.html#Filter-enum), you should simply pass `QDir::AllDirs` with your previous filters.

> QDir::AllDirs - List all directories; i.e. don't apply the filters to directory names.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But wats the solution to it? How can I display only mp3/mpeg files?

Comment: You are already displaying only mp3/mpeg files. I assume you also want to display folders? Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I dont want to display folders. I know I am already displaying mp3 files but only the ones present inside the main folder and not the ones inside subfolders.Have a look at `SONGS` folder, it has subfolders inside where mp3 files are present but are still not displayed on treeview. My intention is to display all mp3 files present in the mainfolder i.e. files inside subfolders should also be displayed.So when I click SONGS, all the mp3 files inside it, subfolders etc must be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

May be try to use not `QFileSystemModel` to your `m_SystemListViewModel`, but create your own model which inherits `QAbstractItemModel`, and use `QStyledItemDelegate` over it.