# Failing to display .mp3 file inside QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, treeview

I have 2 tree views in my .ui. One treeview is `DriveView` and other is `DriveListView`. Now I have written a code which displays the drives of my system in `DriveView. I have done it as follows:

```
// Gets called when application starts
void DetailView::onCamStartup()
{
   m_SystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
   m_SystemListViewModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
   m_SystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
   ui->DriveView->setModel(m_SystemModel);
   ui->DriveListView->setModel(m_SystemListViewModel);

   // regard less how many columns you can do this using for:
   for(int nCount = 1; nCount < m_SystemModel->columnCount(); nCount++)
      ui->DriveView->hideColumn(nCount);
}
```

Now once i click a particular drive in my `DriveView` it shows me the subfolders inside it. What i basically need to do is to iterate/traverse the entire drive and search for `.mp3` files inside. Basically check all folders and subfolders for it. Once it locates the files, it should display them in my another Treeview i.e. `DriveListView`. I have written a following code for it:

```
void DetailView::on_DriveView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
QString sPath = m_SystemModel->fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath();
ui->DriveListView->setRootIndex(m_SystemListViewModel->setRootPath(sPath));

m_SystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
m_SystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs );
m_SystemListViewModel->setFilter( QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );

QStringList m_list;
QDirIterator dirIt(sPath,QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

while (dirIt.hasNext())
{
    dirIt.next();
    if (QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).isFile())
    {
        if (QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).suffix() == "mp3")
        {
            qDebug()<<dirIt.filePath();
            m_list<<dirIt.filePath();
            m_list.append(dirIt.filePath());
        }
    }

    QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel();
    model->setStringList(m_list);
    m_SystemListViewModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);
}
}
```

Whenever I click the subfolders which have mp3 files, it displays them in treeview. This is were I am facing the problem. When I click the mail folder, nothing gets displayed. Ideally I want to display all the mp3 files present in main folder and its subfolders to be displayed. I have put `qDebug()<<dirIt.filePath();` and when i run the app and click a drive, this prints me all the `.mp3` files in Application Output but it doesnt display them in the treeview i.e. `DriveListView`.

Comment: Duplication. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473689/fails-to-display-mp3-files-in-treeview-in-qt

Comment: Whats wrong with your previous question so you had to write new one?

Comment: @troyane: still not finding the appropriate answer. I would appreciate if you could help

Comment: @KamilKlimek: Still not finding the right answer. Spent a lot of time to figure out the issue but failing.

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. You shouldn't spam with new question about same thing only because you didn't get an answer you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are iterating over all subdirs manually anyway, try using a `QStringListModel` for  `m_SystemListViewModel`.  This way, you can directly display `m_list` in the view. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlistmodel.html

Alternatively, it looks like a `QSortFilterProxyModel` might be used to filter the displayed results in the list view, but I have never used it. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html

Comment: Well when I use `QStringListModel`, it displays all the .mp3 files but only when the folders are clicked. What I mean to say is `Songs--> Folder1, Folder 2.` If i click `Folder1` it displays mp3 files in it, similarly if I click `Folder2` it shows mp3 files. But when i click `Songs` nothing gets displayed. Ideally I would want all the files present in Folder1, folder2 etc to be displayed when I click `Songs` folder. You understood what i am trying to say? :)

Comment: In `on_DriveView_clicked` you are now creating a new `QStringModel` every time, but you are not assigning it to a view. Try `m_SystemListViewModel = new QStringListModel(this)` in `onCamStartup` and then set the string list in `on_DriveView_clicked`:`m_SystemListViewModel->setStringList(m_list);`

Comment: so you mean I need to set m_SystemListViewModel as `QStringListModel` in header file or what??? I tried doing it but throws error `cannot convert 'QStringListModel*' to 'QFileSystemModel*' in assignment` and `'class QFileSystemModel' has no member named 'setStringList'` since its of type QFileSystemModel

Comment: Yes, you need to change the header declaration to `QStringListModel*` as well. The point is that you only need to initialize and assign the model to a view once and then update the model's contents whenever a directory is selected. This way, you will see all the files you found in the subdirectories and stored in `m_list`.